# The set of minimums of a continuous function is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is this statement true or false? I was asked to prove that it is true in my homework but I think it is false. Just think of the $f(x)=x$ where between the values $x=\frac{1}{2^k}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ I add a little bump. Then the minimums would acummulate towards $x=0$ and that set would not be closed. Am I wrong?

Comment: An example simpler to construct (but harder to prove) would be $f:x \mapsto x \sin \left( \dfrac 1 x \right)$.

Comment: Just take any set $S$ that is not closed and not dense anywhere, and then $f:x \mapsto d(x,S)$ would be a counter-example.

Comment: Are you asking about local minima?

Comment: My second comment is invalidated. The zero set is actually $\bar{S}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as asked is straightforward to answer and is a consequence of continuity.

If $f$ is continuous and $m = \min_x f(x)$, then the set of minimums $f^{-1}(\{m\})$ is closed.

**However**, I suspect the question was about the set of local minimisers
in which case the answer is in the negative.

Here is an example of a continuous function where the global maximiser is an accumulation point of the local minimisers.

Let $u(x) = -|x|, l(x) = -{3 \over 2}|x|$.

Define $f(0) = 0$, and define $f$ on $[{1 \over n+1},{1 \over n}]$ as
follows:

Choose some point $x_n \in ({1 \over n+1},{1 \over n})$ such that
$l(x_n) < \min (u({1 \over n+1}), u({1 \over n}))$ and define
the graph of $f$ by joining the points
$({1 \over n+1}, u({1 \over n+1}))$,
$(x_n,l(x_n))$,
$({1 \over n}, u({1 \over n}))$.

Let $f$ be even to complete the definition.

It is clear that each $x_n$ is a local minimiser and $x_n \to 0$, the
global maximiser.

Comment: Can you cite a proof?

Comment: @DHMO: This is one definition of continuity if follows form the fact that the inverse image of an open set is open. However, I think the OP is asking about local minima.

Comment: How does that follow from the definition?

Comment: How do you address my second comment on the original question? $y=0$ is a global minimum in that case (as well as local minima).

Comment: This seems to be about the set of inputs where the output is an absolute minimum. I read the question as if it was about local minima.

Comment: Never mind. the zero set of my function would be $\bar{S}$.

Comment: @DHMO: Its pretty standard stuff, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function, for example. The question here is local vs. global minima.

Comment: It is straightforward (but tedious) to give an example of a function whose local minimisers have an accumulation point at a global maximiser.

Comment: @DHMO:  Per your "second comment", $d(x,S) = 0$ for all $x\in \overline{S}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$, continuous.

We denote m := min f(x) with $x \in (a,b)$.

Without further restriction we can assume that $f(a)≠ m, f(b)≠m$

Suppose: $x_0 \in (a,b), \quad f(x_0)≠m, \quad \varepsilon := f(x_0) - m > 0$

f is continous => $\exists \delta > 0$ : $\forall x \in (a,b)$:

$$|x-x_0| < \delta \quad => \quad x \in (a,b) \quad |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$$

E.g. $B_\delta \subset (a,b)$ and $f(x) \ne m$ $\forall x \in B_\delta$

but $B_\delta \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open and $B:= \bigcap\limits_{f(x) \ne m} B_\delta(x) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is too.

Now remark that $B' := B \cap (a,b)$ is the set of all $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) \ne m$. $B'$ is open in the subspace (a,b), and it's complement e.g {$x \in (a,b) | f(x) = m$} is closed.

QED

Edit: If we can't find such a $a$ or $b$ there is a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that f(x) constant is for $x \le c$ or $x \ge c$. And if you can't either of them f is a constant function.